# WPF Binding to the same UIElement (Grid) in two views

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, uielement

I have strange problem. Here's some code:

**XAML of first view:**

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <vm:BendingTabViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
.......
<ItemsControl Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DrawingToolViewModel.Grid, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Grid Width="200" Height="340" Margin="0,30,0,0"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
```

**Code (viemodel of first view):**

```
//here I wrap DrawingToolViewModel
public DrawingToolViewModel DrawingToolViewModel { get; set; }

//here is the method that open new window
public void OpenRPlacementWindow(object obj)
{
    BendingReinforcementPlacementWindowView
    bendingReinforcementPlacementWindowView = new
    BendingReinforcementPlacementWindowView();
    //here i pass the same DrawingToolViewModel to viemodel of second view
    bendingReinforcementPlacementWindowView.DataContext = bendingRPlacementWindowViewModel;
        bendingReinforcementPlacementWindowView.ShowDialog();
    }
```

**XAML of second view:**

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DrawingToolViewModel.Grid, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style>
                <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="0"/>
                <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="0"/>
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Grid Width="200" Height="340" Margin="0,30,0,0"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
```

**Code (viemodel of second view):**

```
private DrawingToolViewModel _drawingToolViewModel;

public DrawingToolViewModel DrawingToolViewModel
    {
        get { return _drawingToolViewModel; }
        set { _drawingToolViewModel = value; }
    }
```

**Finnaly, code of DrawingToolViewModel:**

```
private DrawingToolModel _drawingToolModel;

public DrawingToolModel DrawingToolModel
{
    get { return _drawingToolModel; }
    set { _drawingToolModel = value; }
}

public ObservableCollection<Grid> Grid
{
    get { return DrawingToolModel.Grid; }
    set
    {
        DrawingToolModel.Grid = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("Grid");
    }
 }
```

**Problem:**

In the first view i'm making some calculation, draw a rectangle, add it to Grid and add this Grid to ObservableCollection called "Grid". It shows in ItemsControl.

When i click button that open new window (this windows wraps the same drawing viewmodel) the rectangle shows in new window but disappear in first... Even when i closed second view and remake calculation and drawing the rectangle doesn't show.

Where i got wrong?

Comment: You should not have UI elements (e.g. Grids) in your model or view model. Try to find an abstract representation of what you want to visualize. Note also that a two-way binding of the ItemsSource property doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thanks for advice about finding abstract representation. I made DataTemplate (Rectangle etc) in ItemsControl.Resourses and bind UIElement properties to appropriate viewmodel properties. Now it's works great. You're right that Two-way binding is pointless here. Thank you very much :)